# Android Dialog how to get the text from the Custom adapter Dialog adapter

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

```
this is my code in my adapter.. the int which indicates the id of the item, but how can i get the text value of the item? i want to display it to my button after selecting the item from the dialog..  

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter,-1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch(which) {
            case 0:
        }
        dialog.dismiss();   
    }
});
```

is there a way to use this code? but from my research onItemSelected can be implemented only to listview and spinner.. but in my case how can  i use it in my custom alert dialog adapter?

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + label, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: You mean you already found the solution? If so, post the solution as answer. Do not put it in question itself. And mark it as accepted. Otherwise it is kind of confusing.

Comment: i see okay. actually it's my first time to answer my own question. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I solve this by adding this to my code.

```
 builder.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter,-1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
            String itemName=adapter.getItem(which);
            button.setText(itemName);   
            dialog.dismiss();   
        }
    });
```

> my adapter variable is declared by `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>` by adding

```
String itemName=adapter.getItem(which);
button.setText(itemName);
```

> The which variable corresponds to the ID position of the item within the dialog and using adapter.getItem() it can call the string value of the item so i display it to my button.

Comment: Accept your answer. :)